# Is SO still using Get Satisfaction?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm looking around on the SO sites for a link to their Get Satisfaction site, but can't find it.  Are we still putting feature requests on there, or should they all now be posted to Meta.SO?

Comment: We never used GS, we used UV.  Though we should have used GS.  GS > UV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All feature requests and bug reports are posted on Meta-SO. Any previous sites used by SO has been discontinued.

Althought I can't recall SO ever using Get Satisfaction, unless you are referring to UserVoice, which Meta has since replaced.

Comment: Everything should be posted on meta and get tagged appropriately.

Comment: UserVoice. That was it.  Thanks.